2 прохода в ffmpeg, по принципу dash
ffmpeg -i {file} -deadline best -pass 1 -passlogfile /var/log/{result['id']} -movflags +faststart
 -c:v libvpx-vp9 -pix_fmt yuv420p
 -an -map 0:v:0 -filter:v:0 scale=-2:144 
 -init_seg_name "init-\$RepresentationID\$.\$ext\$"
 -media_seg_name "chunk-\$RepresentationID\$-\$Number%05d\$.\$ext\$"
 -dash_segment_type webm
 -use_template 1 -use_timeline 0 -seg_duration 10
 -adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=v id=1,streams=a"
 -f dash /dev/null &&
ffmpeg -i {file} -deadline best -pass 2 -passlogfile /var/log/{result['id']} -movflags +faststart
 -c:v libvpx-vp9 -pix_fmt yuv420p
 -map 0:a:0 -map 0:v:0 -filter:v:0 scale=-2:144
 -init_seg_name "init-\$RepresentationID\$.\$ext\$"\
 -media_seg_name "chunk-\$RepresentationID\$-\$Number%05d\$.\$ext\$"
 -dash_segment_type webm
 -use_template 1 -use_timeline 0 -seg_duration 10
 -adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=v id=1,streams=a"
 -f dash {path}dash.mpd

C одним проходом все работает, но как быть когда необходимо выполнить операцию дважды. Причем получить на выходе сегменты, результат для воспроизведения по принципу dash.
Использую кодек libvpx-vp9, формат webm. В примере один видеопоток, на самом деле их несколько. Дабы не нагружать...
С одним проходом работает, при попытке сделать два. Получаю ответ
Error opening file /var/log/269-1.log.
[vost#0:1/libvpx-vp9 @ 0x558be0ce3840] Error reading log file '/var/log/269-1.log' for pass-2 encoding
Error opening output file /var/www/site/uploads/video/269/dash.mpd.
Error opening output files: Input/output error

Не понимаю, понятно что не находит файл 269-1.log, в папке только 269-0.log
Как это исправить, что не так делаю?
Рабочий вариант в один проход
ffmpeg -i {file} -deadline best
 -c:v libvpx-vp9 -pix_fmt yuv420p 
 -map 0:a:0 -map 0:v:0 -filter:v:0 scale=-2:144
 -init_seg_name "init-\$RepresentationID\$.\$ext\$"
 -media_seg_name "chunk-\$RepresentationID\$-\$Number%05d\$.\$ext\$"
 -dash_segment_type webm
 -use_template 1 -use_timeline 1 -seg_duration 10
 -adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=v id=1,streams=a"
 -f dash {path}dash.mpd

Как сделать обработку видео в два прохода??

Какую операцию?

Дважды выполнить команду ffmpeg

В чем дело, как в моем случаи выполнить 2 прохода?

Хелп, сутки просидел, ничего, весь интернет облазал....

Добавил вариант преобразования видео в один проход, как сделать 2 прохода? Одни ошибка...

Объясни понятно, что за 2 прохода? Две обработки потока одна за другой? Или два выходных результата? Или что? Вообще не понял, что ты делаешь...

Возможно будет полезно https://stackoverflow.com/a/44494445/6750422

https://developers.google.com/media/vp9/settings/vod?hl=ru

Два прохода делать необходимо для достижения меньшего веса файла, без потери качества. Только с данной целью выполняется это. Два прохода, это тоже самое что если запустить 2 раза команду. Только во втором проходе обрабатываем выход первого не сохраняя в файл...

Ошибка при двухпроходном варианте возникает когда пытаемся выполнить операцию с многопоточность. Когда в одном видеофайле, несколько видеопотоков разного качества.

mpd на сколько я понимаю это файл xml т.е. текстовый содержащий информацию о стриме вот тут можно посмотреть пример этого текстового файла, скорее всего из-за этого и возникает ошибка, т.е. мое мнение это преобразование в mpd нужно делать только во втором проходе.
